# React Native Listview leaving space

Tags: javascript, ios, listview, react-native

I'm trying to implement a listview in React Native. Everything was fine when I was just calling the component `Accounts` but since I put it into a NavigatorIOS the Listview is leaving some space before the first item : see [here](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/312513Capturedcran20150407175543.png) and when I scroll [here](http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/911775Capturedcran20150407175931.png).

Here is my code :

**index.ios.js**

```
var RemoteX1 = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        style={styles.container}
        initialRoute={{
          title: 'Accounts',
          component: Accounts,
        }}/>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

**accounts.js**

```
var people = [
  {
    title: "Papa",
    favouriteChannels: []
  },
  {
    title: "Maman",
    favouriteChannels: []
  },
  {
    title: "Kids",
    favouriteChannels: []
  },
  {
    title: "Invité",
    favouriteChannels: []
  }
];

var Accounts = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    return {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(people),
    }
  },
  renderRow: function(person) {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPressRow}>
        <Text style={styles.account}>{person.title}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.panel}>
          <Text style={styles.icon}>&#xF0C6;</Text>
          <Text style={styles.welcome}>BIENVENUE</Text>
          <ListView 
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this.renderRow}
            style={styles.listView} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  panel: {
    backgroundColor: '#67F072',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingLeft: 50,
    paddingRight: 50,
  },
  icon: {
    color: '#67B7F0',
    fontFamily: 'CanalDemiRomainG7',
    fontSize: 40
  },
  welcome: {
    color: '#67B7F0',
    fontFamily: 'CanalDemiRomainG7'
  },
  account: {
    color: '#000000',
    height: 30,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'CanalDemiRomainG7'
  },
})
```

Does anyone has any idea of what's going on ? Thanks

Comment: You need to edit your answer with a reduced test case. At the moment there is a lot of extraneous information that stops us front working out the problem. Cut it down to the bare minimum that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I don't think I deserved the -1 for this ... 
Well I actually put the all code of the Listview and NavigatorIOS because I don't know from where the bug is coming. Is it the 'CSS' or the 'JS' code ? I'll try to remove some code

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Ok so, I found the answer, I post it here for anyone who run into the same issue.

An issue has been posted on Github [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/721) . 
It is necessary to add to the `ListView` the parameter `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}`.
Problem Solved.

Answer (score 35):

This only happens when you have a ScrollView or ListView with TabBarIOS. You can remove the extra space at the top if you put `automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}`

However, the ScrollView will not completely be shown because the bottom portion of it will be hidden under the TabBarIOS. To fix this add `contentInset={{bottom:49}}` adjust the height according to your needs.

here is the code:

```
<ListView
  contentInset={{bottom:49}}
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
>
```

Comment: I also had the spacing without having a `TabBarIOS`

Answer (score 10):

If you're trying to achieve this in android..contentInset is iOS specific, to manage this on android you need to set the property inside of `<ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
</ListView>`

Then in your stylesheets.create

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  contentContainer: {
    paddingBottom: 100 
  }
```

* I realise that op is asking for an iOS solution, just adding the android solution for people passing and if op decides he's fed up with iOS