# A lot of space between two scrollviews because wrap - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, scrollview

I am creating different scrollviews and the view is not correct. Between ScrollView End and ScrollView Start there is a long space and I don't know what style to modify to avoid that. 
When the scrollview is set to wrap, the long space appear!

Any idea?

I am creating something like this:

```
 <View>
<ScrollView
    contentContainerStyle={{
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignContent: "space-around"
    }}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    contentInSet={{ bottom: 49 }}
    style={{ paddingBottom: 0, marginBottom: 0 }}
>
    <Text>Testing</Text>
    <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={globalStyles.COMMON_STYLES.scrollView}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        contentInSet={{ bottom: 49 }}
        style={{ padding: 0, margin: 0 }}
    >
        <Text>ScrollView End</Text>
    </ScrollView>
    //Here is the problem!!! Lot of space in the IOS Simulator.
    <Text>ScrollView Start</Text>
    <ScrollView>
        <Text>Test</Text>
    </ScrollView>
</ScrollView>
</View>;

 globalStyles.COMMON_STYLES.scrollview
   scrollView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
 }
```

There is a long space up to the following scrollview:
[image]

Comment: you have two adjacent scrollviews contained within one big outer scrollview, why?

Comment: I don't work in react-native but that `contentInSet={{bottom: 49}}`  looks suspicious.

Comment: Try to find out if there is any child component, or the scrollview itself with the "flex: 1" style property. If yes, try to remove that.

Comment: Hi, I have removed all the options and delete all the options you commented. `contentInSet={{bottom: 49}}`was a test from this page [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29496054/react-native-listview-leaving-space)

Comment: hi Daniel, i wanted to have 1 fixed text, scrollview, 1 fixed text and another scrollview. that is why i have an outer scrollview.

Comment: I wanted to use some fixed headers and so on... and I found finally the solution in the new component FlatList. It was not easy but now it is great. SectionList is also great to have sections. Thanks all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this on ScrollView

```
automaticallyAdjustContentInsets = {false}
```